# Asymptote (XeLaTeX): Use custom-defined colors/Call drawing functions from external file

Tags: xetex, color, diagrams, asymptote, latexmk

I'm quite new to Asymptote, although it's great to manipulate vector graphics within LaTeX. Specifically, I'm using XeLaTeX.

What I'm trying to do is to change the color of a vector graphic to whatever one I defined with a `\definecolor` command (using the `xcolor` package), and others previously defined with the `dvipsnames` option. Also, I'm trying not to put the Asymptote code in the LaTeX file I'm working on, as it's quite big, and to have the opportunity to reuse it in future documents. Unfortunately, I tried with no luck.

I partially got Asymptote working with colors like `red` and `yellow` (the standard ones for `xcolor` without options), and with the code attached to the `.tex` file, as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=4in, paperheight=3in,margin=2cm}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myColor}{HTML}{B28B3C}

\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{asydef}
  settings.outformat = "pdf";
  import pstoedit;

  void star(pen color=black) {
    currentpen += 0.5bp;
    currentpen += squarecap;
    currentpen += miterjoin;
    currentpen += linetype(" ",false);
    fill((691.141,600.863)--(703.473,569.43)--(743.625,569.496)
        --(711.098,550.133)--(723.578,518.742)--(691.141,538.207)
        --(658.703,518.742)--(671.184,550.133)--(638.656,569.496)
        --(678.805,569.43)--cycle,color+evenodd);
  }
\end{asydef}

\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \textcolor{myColor}{\textbf{A text with the custom color!}}\\[1cm]
  \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
    \begin{asy}[width=2.5cm]
      star(color=blue);
    \end{asy}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
    \begin{asy}[width=2.5cm]
      //star(color=Purple);
      //star(color=myColor);
      star(color=red);
    \end{asy}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

And here's the latexmkrc file (to use `latexmk` to compile):

```
sub asy {return system("asy \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

It's worth mentioning comments in Asymptote are `//`.

Compiling the `.tex` file as it's here, the output is shown in this image (the text color is the custom one):

[image: Output of compiled MWE (as it is)]

When I try to compile with `latexmk -xelatex star.tex` using a `dvipsnames` or custom color for the second star (i.e. leaving only one of the three provided lines uncommented), I get the following error:

```
star-2.asy: 29.12: no matching variable 'myColor' <-- Custom color
star-2.asy: 28.12: no matching variable 'Purple'  <-- dvipsnames color
```

In fact, I even get the same error when I try to put the contents of `\begin{asydef}...\end{asydef}` in an external file, say `code.asy`, and link it with the instruction `\asyinclude{code.asy}`. That's why you see the code in `star.tex`.

Is there a way to get rid of these errors to accomplish the task I'm trying to do? Any help/clues will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure if it is possible to give an color from the `xcolor` package to asymptote. With `inline` option and the LaTeX `textcolor` command everything is ok since it is a LaTeX command. But when you specify `Purple` or `Mycolor` asymptote does understand, the color is not defined in an asy way (see `pen` definition). For color definition (`purple` is defined for example) please consult http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Pens.html#Pens .

Comment: To link `star.asy` to all the asy environments in your TeX file, include the command `import star;` or `include 'star.asy';` in your `asydef` environment.

Comment: If you want to put the code for a single picture in an `asy` file, you can use the `\asyinclude` command to include the picture (and hopefully let `latexmk` and other tools know about the dependency). But the only way to simultaneously affect all Asymptote code in your TeX file is using the `asydef` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this by defining the color in TeX code. However, there is a way to get the custom color you want. Using an [html color converter](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp) and inputting `#B28B3C` for your custom color, it appears that the cmyk code for the color is `cmyk(0%, 22%, 66%, 30%)`. Similarly, if you ask for `Purple` from the color converter, you get the cmyk code `cmyk(0%, 100%, 0%, 50%)`. You can use these colors in Asymptote by adding the following lines to your `asydef` environment:

```
pen myColor = cmyk(0, 0.22, 0.66, 0.30);
pen Purple = cmyk(0, 1.00, 0, 0.50);
```

This is probably the simplest solution you're going to get.

If you really, really want TeX to do all the work for you, you might try the following:

1. Switch from the `asymptote` package to the [`asypictureB` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb?lang=en). (The TeX commands are different, but the actual Asymptote code is identical.) This allows you to use **purely expandable** TeX macros directly in the Asymptote code by prefixing them with `@` instead of `\`. It has other advantages and disadvantages compared to the `asymptote` package; these are detailed in the [asypictureB documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/asypictureb/asypictureB.pdf).
2. Having completed step 1, patch into the `xcolor` package and ensure that every time a color is defined (including those colors pre-defined by the package), a **purely expandable** macro is defined that can be parsed by Asymptote. For instance, after `\definecolor{myColor}{HTML}{B28B3C}`, there should exist a command `\myColorAsy` or similar that expands to `cmyk(0, 0.22, 0.66, 0.30)` or to `rgb(178/255, 139/255, 60/255)`. Then, when you want to use this color in your Asymptote code, use `@myColorAsy`. Note that this will recreate the color every time you use it, so technically the Asymptote code will run more slowly; but for most purposes the difference will be imperceptible.

Personally, I think step 2 is way more work than it's worth. But if some enterprising soul wants to give a pure (La)TeX solution explaining how to hook into the `xcolor` package and achieve this, I'll certainly upvote it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand how to do it. Well, and what about calling the function from another file? As I stated in the question I get the same error for that, and I don't know why =(

Comment: See my comment to your question.

Comment: The two proposed methods are interesting. Thanks for your effort!